# upgrade from mvc3 to mvc5 in my nopcommerce customized solution

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-assembly

I have nopcommerce solution version 2.3 developed using `c# MVC3` and `framework 4.0` and now I tried to upgrade to `mvc5` and `framework 4.5.1`.
     These steps was done.

```
 1. open my solution via VS_2013 and Update All framework to 4.5.1  in all project from properties and web .config.
 2. change the references of nuget packege and take it from nopcommerce 3.6 to my solution package folder.
 3. change the dll's of (EntityFramework, Autofac,Autofac.mvc, FluentValidation,  and mvc).
 4. getting build succeed.
 5. now I have this error
```

> Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 
>     [Exception: Could not load file or assembly 'FluentValidation, Version=3.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a82054b837897c66' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
>   Could not load file or assembly 'FluentValidation, Version=3.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a82054b837897c66' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'FluentValidation, Version=3.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a82054b837897c66' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
>   Could not load file or assembly 'FluentValidation, Version=3.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a82054b837897c66' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
>   Could not load file or assembly 'FluentValidation, Version=3.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a82054b837897c66' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
>   Could not load file or assembly 'FluentValidation, Version=3.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a82054b837897c66' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
>   Could not load file or assembly 'FluentValidation, Version=3.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a82054b837897c66' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
>   Could not load file or assembly 'FluentValidation, Version=3.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a82054b837897c66' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
>   Could not load file or assembly 'FluentValidation, Version=3.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a82054b837897c66' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
>   Could not load file or assembly 'FluentValidation, Version=3.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a82054b837897c66' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
>   Could not load file or assembly 'FluentValidation, Version=3.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a82054b837897c66' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
>   Could not load file or assembly 'FluentValidation, Version=3.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a82054b837897c66' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
>   Could not load file or assembly 'FluentValidation, Version=3.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a82054b837897c66' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
>   ]
>      System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext context, HttpApplication app) +12600141
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +175
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +304
>      System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +404
>      System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +475

Comment: Looks like this line `'FluentValidation, Version=3.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a82054b837897c66' ` is telling you what the issue is. It's looking for a .net 4.5.1 version of this and not finding it.

Comment: Try removing that reference, and then adding it again through the NuGet package manager. That should pull down a compatible version.

Comment: @MichaelMcPherson McPherson which version of FluentValidation compatible with 4.5.1 framework ?

Comment: also be sure you set the assembly to be copied to local (right click on the assembly > properties). so the assembly gets copied to the output folder

Comment: @HatemAl-Aqrabawi Some googling suggests 5.6.2 is the current version.

Comment: Good point @Ahmedilyas, that one has caught me more than once.

Comment: @Ahmedilyas i also do that

Comment: i see nopcommerce 3.6 it they used FluentValidation.dll 5.6.2 and in the web.config  file add this      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="FluentValidation" publicKeyToken="a82054b837897c66" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.4.0.0" newVersion="3.4.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>  ....  and i do this too but i have this error

Comment: where i can find this dll physically in drivers ?